# What is the name of this Japanese physical keyboard layout that's made for Japan but has no visible Kana?

Tags: keyboard, macbook, keyboard-layout, language, japanese

My employer has tis marked as a Japanese keyboard.

This keyboard has only latin characters, a few extra punctuation marks including the Yen, and a different Capslock key.

Every Japanese keyboard I can find has both Latin characters and Hiragana on it. The only one that I can find available for current MacBooks is the JIS which works that way and has non-centered Latin characters.

Is this an Apple-specific keyboard that's no longer made? Do the Kana only appear when you toggle something?

[image: 13" MacBook A1989 (c.2018)]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this product was incorrectly labeled and this layout is configured for Chinese Pinyin input.